# Is this number-of-subsets question appropriately structured for Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788483/find-the-number-of-subsets-of-1-2-3-4-5-dots-2000-the-sum-of-whose-elemen) has apparently been kicking around for about a week now. While the core content is interesting, at this point it seems to be mostly an opportunity for the poster to go on at length about their approaches to the problem, essentially writing a paper over several answers. It feels (and I do not mean this to be derogative) like a 'reddit' approach to math.se, and I feel like the way the question currently sits is well outside the Math.SE guidelines particularly on the 'open-ended discussion' front. OTOH, I'm not confident enough in any of these assessments (especially given the question's positive reputation) to explicitly flag it.

Comment: You can always raise an "In Need of Moderator Attention" flag.  As you say, the question (and multiple, multiple answers) are not in-line with the ethos of SE.

Comment: FYI they reposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794840/find-the-number-of-subsets-of-1-2-3-4-5-dots-2000-the-sum-of-whose-elemen

Comment: OP should be encouraged to write a textbook on Number Theory – but to do it somewhere else.

Comment: @Jonathan, that new question got closed as a duplicate of the older one. Then OP spat the dummy, and deleted it.

Comment: It seems that the question linked by Steven is "deleted", in the sense that it's still there but the whole body is gone now.

Comment: The latest message from OP is the comment, "I'm trying to empty the place and clean it up again" OP has also deleted all the answers he/she had posted.

Comment: Most recent development: OP attempted to turn the question into a "sandbox", moderator Xander put the kibosh on that.